# Projection of vector $v$ onto a plane with normal vector $n$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, projection

$v$ is a vector. $n$ is normal vector for a (hyper)plane. What is the projection of $v$ onto that plane?

---

In three dimensions, let the projection be $x$. We have:

$$x\cdot n=0$$

$$(v-x)\cdot x=0$$

$$(v-x)\cdot n=|v-x|$$

These three equations might simply to:

$$v\cdot n=|v-x|$$
$$v\cdot x-x^2=0$$

I don't know how to proceed..

Seems like: $$x=v-(n\cdot v)n?$$

Comment: You have an unstated assumption that $\lVert n\rVert=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

The projection of $v$ onto a line directed by $n$ is
$$p_n(v)=\frac{v\cdot n}{n\cdot n}\, n.$$

Comment: $x=v-(n\cdot v)n$? normal vector is a unit vector

Comment: If the normal vector is normalised, yes, that's the correct formula. The formula I used was more general and is valid in any inner product space.

Comment: What if $v$ is in $\mathbb R^k$ and the plane has a lot of independent normal vectors?

Comment: What I wrote was valid for a hyperplane, in which case there is a single normalised normal vector.

Comment: @ Ok I would just open another question. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Just a first thought about your more general case: I think it would need to consider projections on a hyperplane containing the pplane, then the projection of the first projection onto a second hyperplane linearly independent from the first, and so on. I might involve some exterior powers (a.k.a. Grassman algebra).